# Hardware button press event while device is sleeping

Tags: android

I am developing a security application. When the user presses a hardware button for a specific amount of time an action will occur.

I need to a react to the press of a hardware button like Power or Volume. 
My application has to work in the background without requiring the user to unlock the screen. The problem is that I cannot catch the event when the button is pressed while the device is 'asleep'

A scenario could be that the user pushes the power button for 3 seconds, which causes an email to be sent.

The `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER` doesn't work in a service and activities are either paused or destroyed.

Any Idea how to solve my problem?

Is there any `BrodcastReceiver` to realize this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for you is to create BroadcastReceiver. But here will be problem of actions to subscribe. Maybe you can find something that is appropriate for you [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Look for "Standard Broadcast Actions".

Comment: In the link it's better to search for string "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system"

Answer (score -2):

use this    buttonId.performClick(); it is used for following purpose .

without clicking that button we can perform the click operation of that button means without clicking that button we can invoke onclick method of that button.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. What is required is to detect an actual button click, not to fake one.

Comment: His application is running in the background and needs to detect a hardware button press, so this is still not helpful.